# NSInvalidArgumentException with stringByAppendingPathComponent

Tags: ios

i have a bundel settings with a string : version

in my bundle settings version = 2.9.1

in my project, if i use this code, all is good :

```
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ma/V_2.9.1/gma2/fixture_layers/ifocus.xml"];
```

if i use this code :

```
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:(@"ma/V_%@/gma2/fixture_layers/ifocus.xml", version)];
```

i have this error :

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextField length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9753190'

Comment: Try `NSString * path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ma/V_%@/gma2/fixture_layers/ifocus.xml", version]];`

Comment: i try this
      NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ma/V_%@/gma2/fixture_layers/ifocus.xml", version]];
    NSLog(@"aaaaaaa %@", path); and i have this error : aaaaaaa /var/mobile/Applications/2D2290A0-6C9B-4260-BBD7-560CCF29A0E6/Documents/ma/V_<UITextField: 0x1564be30; frame = (116 225; 97 30); text = '2.9.1'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1564c9e0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1564bf70>>/gma2/fixture_layers/ifocus.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already including multiple /'s in your string, there's no advantage to using stringByAppendingPathComponent. So you may as well just use:

```
NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"ma/V_%@/gma2/fixture_layers/ifocus.xml", version];
```

Another option, that gives you the benefit of stringByAppendingPathComponent, is to break it right down like this:

```
NSString* path = [[[[[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ma"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V_%@", version]] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gma2"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fixture_layers"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ifocus.xml"];
```

But that's kind of ugly.

Comment: i use NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"ma/V_%@/gma2/fixture_layers/ifocus.xml", version];
    NSLog(@"aaaaaaa %@", path); and i have this error : aaaaaaa /var/mobile/Applications/2D2290A0-6C9B-4260-BBD7-560CCF29A0E6/Documentsma/V_<UITextField: 0x14691170; frame = (116 225; 97 30); text = '2.9.1'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x14691d20>; layer = <CALayer: 0x146912b0>>/gma2/fixture_layers/ifocus.xml

Comment: Looks like your `version` variable is a `UITextField`, not an `NSString` with the version number. So use `version.text` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> NSString * path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ma/V_%@/gma2/fixture_layers/ifocus.xml", version]];